# Clone a python virtualenv to an offline server

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to clone a python virtualenv to a server that's not connected to the internet. I searched different forums but didn't find a clear answer. Here are the methods I found and the problems I have with each :

**Method 1 : (safest but most time consuming)**

Save all the libraries via a `pip freeze > requierments.txt` then go download each one manually and store them in a directory. Copy this directory to the offline server, then create a new virtualenv in the offline server, and install all requirements from the files downloaded.
To avoid downloading each one by hand I used `pip download -r requirements.txt -d wheelfiles` in the source machine, but I couldn't find a way to install all the packages in one command. But I could use a script with a loop to go through each one. The problem is when even the source server doesn't have internet connection to download these packages.

**Method 2 : (less recommended but I didn't understand why)**

Is to simply copy the virtualenv directory with all its files to the offline machine, both machines should have apparently the same Python version, and you'll have to manually modify some hardcoded paths for example modifying all files containing `sourceserver\user1\dev\virtualenv` with `targetserver\user4\dev\virtualenv`  Usually the files to modify start with activate* or pip*.
But this method is said to be not recommended but I don't understand why.

Also if this method work without problems, can I copy the virtualenv folder from a linux server to a windows server and vice versa ?

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: Method 2 does not work when you switch from ARM to x86 or vice versa and it does not work when you switch from Linux to Windows, because the binaries are different (ELF versus PE).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install all the requirements using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which means the options are:

1. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
2. `pip download -r requirements.txt -d wheelfiles`
3. `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links path/to/wheels`

or

1. Ensure target machine is the same architecture, OS, and Python version
2. Copy virtual environment
3. Modify various hardcoded paths in files

It should be clear why the former is preferred, especially as it is completely independent of Python version, machine architecture, OS, etc.

Additionally, the former means that the `requirements.txt` can be committed to source control in order to recreate the environment on demand on any machine, including by other people and when the original machine or copy of the virtual environment is not available. In terms of size, the `requirements.txt` file is also significantly smaller than an entire virtual environment.

Comment: Are you sure, that for option architecture doesn't matter? For the project I'm making this work it downloads files like `uvloop-0.14.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` with the arch in it's name.

Comment: @JensKohl It downloads the correct package for your machine no matter what machine you're on, that's the point. The requirements.txt doesn't list an architecture, pip knows what your architecture is when it runs.

Comment: So the architecture of the machine which downloads the files must match the machine which should install them, correct? If so is there a way to specify the architecture before downloading?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've just realised which problem you were pointing out. In general you should be able to use the `--platform` option to specify which platform to download for, though there are caveats around packages for which wheels aren't available, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287077/pip-downloading-dependencies-to-specific-platform-including-non-binaries).